# Constructing the instances in an Enum without modifying the Enum class

Tags: java, enums

I apologize if my question lacks clarity,

I'm currently working on a school assignement where I have to use the following Enum class:

```
public enum Seeds {
TOMATE,
CONCOMBRE,
SALADE,
PATATE,
BETTERAVE;
}
```

Rather then making a whole bunch of constants for the buy price, sell price and maturation time of each seed and having to type them out each time, I wanted to assign attributes to each enum directly in the class like so:

```
public enum Seeds {
TOMATE(2.00, 3.50, 5),
CONCOMBRE(1.00, 2.50, 6),
SALADE(1.50, 4.50, 8),
PATATE(2.50, 3.50, 4),
BETTERAVE(2.00, 4.00, 10);

private final double 
                buy_price,
                sell_price;
private final int
                maturation_time;

public Seeds(double buy_price, sell_price, int maturation_time) {
    this.buy_price = buy_price;
    this.sell_price = sell_price;
    this.maturation_time = maturation_time;
}...
```

and return their attributes with getters.

However, my teacher told me that I cannot modify the provided Enum class... so I was wondering if it was possible to construct the seeds in another class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't modify the Seeds enum, you could create a POJO to hold all the info you need like this:

```
public class Seed {
    private Seeds seedType;
    private double buyPrice;
    private double sellPrice;
    private int maturationTime;
    // constructor, getters and setters here
}
```

It would be better to add the properties and a constructor to the Seeds enum though.

Comment: I iterated on your idea, this is what I ended up doing `public class Magasin {

    private final static int BUY = 0, SELL = 1, RIPE = 2;
    private final static double[][] MAGASIN = { { 2.00, 3.50, 5.0 }, // Tomate
     { 1.00, 2.50, 6.0 },
     { 1.50, 4.50, 8.0 },
     { 2.50, 3.50, 4.0 },
     { 2.00, 4.00, 10.0 },
    };
// getters...
}`

Comment: I basically declared a STORE matrix constant with all the data in it... I wanted to try Sean's idea, but I have no experience using interfaces, and couldn't really understand their function on my own.

Comment: That works too.  You could also add getters like this: `public double getBuyPrice(Seeds seedType) { return MAGASIN[seedType.ordinal()][BUY]; }`

Comment: Exactly what I did, I just couldn't paste the whole code in a single comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom class that encapsulates the different price types, and keep a `Map<Seed, YourCustomPricesClass>` to store the relations.

> See: [the Map interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) in the Java Tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, but you are eroding the main intent behind creating an enum. If you are going to create a modifiable state of a class, technically you are creating a new object. If that is the case, You don't even need an enum at first place, just stick with class.